# How to exclude regex text between two matches?

Tags: regex, perl, batch-file

I have a set specific repeating text blocks. They have a dynamic file name, and a dynamic message. For every filename I want to extract the message.

```
Filename: dynamicFile.txt
Property: some property to neglect
Message: the message I want
Time: dynamicTime
```

I want to extract the part after message, which would be: `the message I want`.

What I have: The following would match anything between Filename and Time.

```
(?<=Filename: %myFileVar%)(?s)(.*)(?=Time:)
```

whereas `%myFileVar%` are dynamic file variables I will feed the expression with.

Now I need to find a way to ommit anything after the filename until the message part. Here I would have to ommit:

```
Property: some property to neglect
Message:
```

How could this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $text;
{
    local $/;
    $text = <DATA>;
}

my $myFileVar = 'dynamicFile.txt';

if ($text =~ /Filename: \Q$myFileVar\E.*?Message: (.*?)\s*Time:/s)
{
   print $1;    
}

__DATA__
Filename: dynamicFile.txt
Property: some property to neglect
Message: the message I want
Time: dynamicTime
```

Note: this assumes that `Time:` always comes right after the message line.  If that is not true, ikegami's solution offers a way to skip any other lines.

**Explanation:**

- You can simply insert a variable into your pattern, and it will be interpolated.
- However, if the variable contains any special regex characters, they will be treated as regex characters. Thus you need to surround the variable with `\Q...\E`, which make everything in between be treated literally.  If you did not do that, the dot in your filename would match any character.
- You don't need to use lookarounds to only capture part of a string.  Instead, use a capture group--any normal sets of parentheses within the pattern will automatically be put into the variables `$1`, `$2`, etc.
- For a simple case like this, it is better to enable single line mode (`s`) as a switch after the pattern. (`/s` instead of `(?s)`).  Turning it on within the pattern is experimental and should only be used if you need it to apply to only part of the pattern.
- `.*?` should be used instead of `.*`.  Otherwise the pattern will match everything from the first `Message:` to the last `Time:` in the file.

Comment: That would include any lines between Message and Time in the capture.

Comment: @ikegami, thanks for pointing out the `\s*` issue.  As I understood the question, there is a fixed format of blocks, so Time will always come right after Message.

Comment: He's already added a field before from his previous question. Some flexibility wouldn't be a bad idea,

Comment: That's very nice solution, thanks! Helps me getting started with perl and regex much better.

Answer (score 1):

```
/
   ^
   Filename: \s* \Q$myFileVar\E \n
   (?: (?!Message:) [^\n]*\n )*
   Message: \s* ([^\n]*) \n
   (?: (?!Time:) [^\n]*\n )*
   Time:
/mx
```

`(?: [^\n]*\n )*` skips any number of lines.

Comment: `(?: [^\n]*\n )*` will match all the way to the end of the text before backtracking to the last Message.

Comment: I meant that it might get the wrong message if there is more than one block in the text.

Answer (score 0):

**Perl can do `\K` Magic**

Adding a late answer because I'm not seeing my favorite solution. In Perl regex, `\K` tells the engine to drop everything we have matched so far from the final match. So you could have used this regex:

```
(?sm)^Filename:.*?Message: \K[^\r\n]+
```

or even:

```
(?m)^Message: \K[^\r\n]+
```

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/kB4rH1).